# Use of several configurable loggers with spdlog

Tags: c++, spdlog

I am using spdlog in a C ++ application, where I have created a class that builds a log pool, with variable content in the pool, which is not always the same, since it is done inside a function that is passed a parameter indicating if you want to have a log only in the console, only in one file or both simultaneously.

In other words, the pool can include a logger to the console plus a logger to a file or only one of the two.

OPTION 1:
I have tried to get this functionality with this code, but it doesn't compile and it shows an error stating that it doesn't support push_back function:

```
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> MyClass::loggerPull;
    spdlog::sinks_init_list loggerList;
        
    if (logToUse == USE_CONSOLE)
      loggerList.push_back(myConsoleLog);
    else if (logToUse == USE_FILE)
      loggerList.push_back(myFileLog);
    else
    {
      loggerList.push_back(myConsoleLog);
      loggerList.push_back(myFileLog);
    }

    loggerPull = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>("mylogger", loggerList.begin(), loggerList.end(), spdlog::thread_pool(), spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block);
```

OPTION 2:
This code compiles and works:

```
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> MyClass::loggerPull;

    if (logToUse == LOG_TO_CONSOLE)
    {
      spdlog::sinks_init_list loggerList = { myConsoleLog };
      loggerPull = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>("mylogger", loggerList.begin(), loggerList.end(), spdlog::thread_pool(), spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block);
    }
    else if (logToUse == LOG_TO_FILE)
    {
      spdlog::sinks_init_list loggerList = { myFileLog };
      loggerPull = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>("mylogger", loggerList.begin(), loggerList.end(), spdlog::thread_pool(), spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block);
    }
    else
    {
      spdlog::sinks_init_list loggerList = { myConsoleLog, myFileLog };
      loggerPull = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>("mylogger", loggerList.begin(), loggerList.end(), spdlog::thread_pool(), spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block);
    }
```

However, I would like to define the loggerList outside of the "if ... else if ..." and use some function similar to push_back or instert in order to add the necessary loggers to the list, similarly as done in OPTION 1.

Is there a function in spdlog that allows adding loggers to an empty loggerList list instead of creating and filling the list in the declaration of loggerList ?

Comment: as `sinks_init_list` is an alias for an initializer list, I don't think It is not meant to be used like that. Did you try to use a `std::vector` ?

Comment: Could you indicate with a small code snippet what would be the correct way to use it with a vector or similar? Thank you.

Comment: just replace `sink_init_list` with `std::vector` and it should be fine. I don't have spdlog available, so I cannot provide you any code

Answer (score 0):

You may consider constructing the list directly as follows:

`loggerPull = std::make_shared<spdlog::async_logger>("mylogger", spdlog::sinks_init_list{myConsoleLog, myFileLog}, spdlog::thread_pool(), spdlog::async_overflow_policy::block);`

Although this will require you to still use an if block, it eliminates the need to create `LoggerList`.